# Как показать авторизацию админки в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

в main layout есть такой код

```
    if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'login') { 
    /**
     * Do not use this code in your template. Remove it. 
     * Instead, use the code  $this->layout = '//main-login'; in your controller.
     */
        echo $this->render(
            'main-login',
            ['content' => $content]
        );
    } else { 
....
}
```

Когда я закрываю доступ к админке не авторизованного пользователя в МОдуле

```
public function behaviors()
    return [
        'access'    =>  [
            'class' =>  AccessControl::className(),
            'denyCallback'  =>  function($rule, $action)
            { 
                //return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['/admin/login/index']);
                throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('Нет доступа');
            },
            'rules' =>  [
                [
                    'allow' =>  true,
                    'matchCallback' =>  function($rule, $action)
                    {
                        return Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin;
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

меня автоматические перенаправляют меня на auth/login. Мне бы хотелось чтобы перенаправили если в строке веду http://site.ru/admin перенаправляли на страницу авторизации админа, например: http://site.ru/admin/login. А если это простой пользователь и он хочется авторизоваться перенаправляли его на страницу http://site.ru/auth/login.

как мне добиться такого результата? Шаблон админки AdminLte

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас админка представлена в виде отдельного модуля, то можно в главном классе модуля(обычно это файл `Module.php` в корне модуля) задать `url` для авторизации при инициализации модуля:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    \Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = '/admin/login';
}
```

То же самое можно добавить в любой контроллер, если нужно отдельно от модуля, или вообще если модули не используются

Comment: Я делал так. но тогда когда перенаправляют на эту страницу admin/login выдает 500 ошибку)

Comment: А если вручную открыть `admin/login` в браузере, ошибки нет?

Comment: нет. Но если не авторизован пользователь то его перенаправляют на авторизацию site/login. А когда пишу \Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = '/admin/login';, то 500 ошибка\

Comment: Проверьте настройки доступа к экшену admin/login, думаю на этот экшен закрыт доступ для неавторизованного пользователя и происходит множественная переадресация, из-за этого и ошибка

Comment: А что если behaviors убрать из Module и написать для каждого контроллера отдельно? Может в этом проблема?!

Comment: Зачем так заморачиваться. У вас же видно что в модуль админки доступ закрыт на все страницы, включая экшен логина. Добавьте исключение в access: `'except' => ['login/index']`